# Identify new gravel road bike from photo

Tags: identify-this-bike, road, gravel, leather

This is a photo I came across earlier this year of a gravel bike that is gorgeous and I would love to know what brand it is.  Hopefully it i identifiable.  Thank you[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles. Do you have any close-up pictures of the components?  Can you at least tell us the make of the components?

Comment: I wonder if it's not sold like that. Almost any matte black frame with clean lines and internal routing, brown leather saddle and bar tape, and tan wall tyres would get the look.

Comment: Hi, I don't have any other photos unfortunately so no info on the components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Done some searching. Looks like it's [Open U.P.(P.E.R.)](https://opencycle.com/up). Even decals match.

**Edit for additional info:**

Groupset: probably [SRAM Force eTAP AXS](https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/gs-frc-e-a1)

Wheels: [Hunt](https://www.huntbikewheels.com/collections/gravel-wheels) (not sure about the model)

Tires: [Specialized Pathfinder Pro](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/pathfinder-pro-2bliss-ready/p/157870?color=334296-157870)

Comment: The sticker where the fork meets the headtube looks very much like that.

Comment: Wow thank you for your help!  It's a nice bike.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Trek Checkpoint but it's quite similar. It might be a Chinese special like an Airwolf frame. Too many bikes have this dropped chainstay now to make it easy to identify and i'm sure the components are a shop or home build rather than a factory build.